# How to execute data inside TableViewCell as a button?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

[image]I am creating an app where in the menus are listed inside `TableViewCell`. The menus are already inside the cell but unfortunately, when I clicked one of the menus, It is not executing the action that the menu should do. For example, i tapped the `logout label` it does not executing `showlogoutDialog`. I already used breakpoints but it seems the data inside the table are just plain text. Image below is the sample output of the table.  Hope you can give some solution regarding this issue. Thank you.

[image: Screen Record]

**DoctorMenuTableCell.swift**

```
class DoctorMenuTableCellTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {


@IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!


override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}
```

**MoreOptionViewController.swift**

```
private let menuIdentifier = "MenuCell"

class MoreOptionViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var doctorMenuTableView: UITableView!

}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

self.doctorMenuTableView.dataSource = self
self.doctorMenuTableView.delegate = self

}

//MARK: Function

func showLogoutDialog() {
    //create alert
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Confirmation",  message: "Are you sure you want to logout?", preferredStyle: .alert)

    //add the actions (button)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "No", style: .default, handler: nil))
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: .default, handler: { (alert) in
        self.logout()
    }))
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

}

func logout() {
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name(deleteUserDataNotificationName), object: nil)
   }

}


extension MoreOptionViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
switch section {  
  case 0:
      return Menu.More.items.count
  default: return 0
 }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let row = indexPath.row

    switch indexPath.section {
    case 0:
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: menuIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! DoctorMenuTableCell

        cell.titleLabel.text = Menu.More.items[row].value

        if row == 1{
            cell.titleLabel.textColor = UIColor.red
            cell.accessoryType = .none   
        }

        return cell
    default:
        return UITableViewCell()
    }
}

func tableView(_tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    switch indexPath.section {
    case 0: break
    case 1:
        switch indexPath.row {
            case 0:
                let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Info", message: "No available data", preferredStyle: .alert)
                alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default))

                self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        case 1: showLogoutDialog()
        default: break
    }

    default: break

    }

}
```

Comment: You are almost done, You are just messed up with `Switch` case. Check my answer below to understand what you did wrong.

Comment: Sometimes especially in cases when you use tableView inside ViewController not TableViewController you need to add numberOfSection = 1 or (how much do you need). After that it starts working as expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your `Did Select` Method, your `cells` are under `Section 0` and `Did Select` work for `section 1`.

Also check `isUserInteractionEnabled` for both `TableView` as well as `Cell` and add breakpoint on `didSelectRowAt` and check which switch case is working.

**Code:**

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
  return 2
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
   switch section {  
     case 0:
         return Menu.More.items.count
     default: return 0
    }
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    switch indexPath.section {
      case 0:
          let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: menuIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! DoctorMenuTableCell
          cell.titleLabel.text = Menu.More.items[row].value

          if indexPath.row == 1{
              cell.titleLabel.textColor = UIColor.red
              cell.accessoryType = .none   
          }

         return cell
      default:
         return UITableViewCell()
      }
 }



func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
   switch indexPath.section {
    case 1: break
    case 0:
         switch indexPath.row {
           case 0:
              let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Info", message: "No available data", preferredStyle: .alert)
              alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default))

              self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil) 
            break
            case 1: showLogoutDialog()
            break
            default: break
         }
         break
         default: break

     }

  }
```

Comment: Hi Thank you also for helping me, I also tried your answer but still not working. I can't figure it out which part was wrong

Comment: @Titus check my updated answer and let me know if you are still having any issue.

Comment: Can you add a `screen record` as a `gif`, for better debugging?

Comment: I'll try if I can add screen record, in which part?

Comment: 'Did select' functionality

Comment: No issue. Let me debug into this

Comment: I added the `screen record` above.

Comment: yeah got the `gif`.

Comment: @Titus check my updated answer. Replace all your `datasource` and `delegate` method with my codes.

Comment: Great to know that :)

Answer (score 0):

Look how many sections you have. You have just one, but inside `didSelectRowAt` you're showing alerts just if section index is 1 which in you case index never is.

You just need to check if row is 0 or 1

```
func tableView(_tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    switch indexPath.row {
    case 0: 
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Info", message: "No available data", preferredStyle: .alert)
        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default))
        present(alertController, animated: true)
    case 1:
        showLogoutDialog()
    default: 
        return
    }
}
```

---

So, if you have only one section, you can also update data source methods. Also you should handle cases that cell isn't in `IndexPath` with row index 1 since cells are dequeued

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return Menu.More.items.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: menuIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! DoctorMenuTableCell

    let row = indexPath.row
    cell.titleLabel.text = Menu.More.items[row].value

    cell.titleLabel.textColor = .black 
    cell.accessoryType = .detailButton

    if row == 1
        cell.titleLabel.textColor = .red
        cell.accessoryType = .none
    }

    return cell
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for helping me, I tried to modify my code and I used your answer but still It is not working. I tried to tapped both menus (Setting and Logout) it is still not executing. :( I am confuse which part my code has error

Answer (score 0):

First Create Extension if UIViewController as Below,

Create a swift File Named Extension.swift or whatever you want,

```
extension UIViewController
{
    func showLogoutDialog() {
        //create alert
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Confirmation",  message: "Are you sure you want to logout?", preferredStyle: .alert)

        //add the actions (button)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "No", style: .default, handler: nil))
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: .default, handler: { (alert) in
            self.logout()
        }))
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
    func logout() {
        print("helllllo")
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name(deleteUserDataNotificationName), object: nil)
    }
}
```

Now call showLogoutDialog() on cellForRowAt,

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
   switch indexPath.section {
    case 1: break
    case 0:
         switch indexPath.row {
           case 0:
              let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Info", message: "your data", preferredStyle: .alert)
              alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default))

              self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil) 
            break
            case 1: showLogoutDialog()
            break
            default: break
         }
         break
         default: break

     }
```